# How do we do a security audit with SecEdit in command line?

Tags: cmd

Does it have something to do with AuditPol?  I'm just stuck, please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: SecEdit sets Windows Audit policy

Comment: Yes but I don't know the exact command for it.

Comment: What are you doing. SecEdit doesn't do security audits. It turns on auditing, which is off by default because it makes the computer slower. You then go to the properties of the object you want audited and specify to audit it. So two steps. Turn it on then specify what. SecEdit only turns it on.